# Вызов AsyncTask из самого себя же

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Здравствуйте. Есть урл, который возвращает статус, необходимо бегать по этому урлу, пока значение не будет равно определенному. Я делаю следующее, вызываю AsyncTask, в doInBackground приходит JSON, который я разбираю. Потом сравниваю статус, если он не равен необходимому, то беру и снова через n сек. вызываю этот же AsyncTask. Как я понял, так делать не правильно. Ибо, память с каждым loopом асинктаска всё больше и больше кушается. Похоже, что предыдущие не завершаются.

```
    public class API_ORDER_GET_STATUS extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Void, JSONObject> {
    Context context;
    String order;
    String id_order;
    public API_ORDER_GET_STATUS(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Map<String, String>... arr) {

        return loadJSON(arr[0]);
    }

    public JSONObject loadJSON(Map<String, String> arr) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // здесь параметры необходимые в запрос добавляем
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", arr.get("phone")));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order", arr.get("order")));
        order = arr.get("order");
        id_order = arr.get("id_order");
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", arr.get("imei")));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", arr.get("hash")));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(arr.get("url"), "POST", params);

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonData) {
        // если какой-то фейл, проверяем на null
        // фейл может быть по многим причинам: сервер сдох, нет сети на устройстве и т.д.

        if (jsonData != null) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonData);
            Log.d("dev", jsonData.toString());
            try {
                String status  = jsonData.getString("c");

                if (status.equals("1")) {
                    JSONObject res = jsonData.getJSONObject("d");
                    //res.getString("status");

                    String pStatus = private_status.getText().toString();
                    if (!pStatus.equals(res.getString("status"))) {
                        if (res.getString("status").equals("accepted")) {
                            header_status.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h4> Машина будет через "+res.getString("feedTime")+" мин.</h4>"));
                        } else if(res.getString("status").equals("complete")) {
                            // Тут мы должны завершать текущее активити, и вызывать новое
                        } else {
                            header_status.setText(Html.fromHtml(getDescriptionStatus(res.getString("status"))));
                        }
                    }
                    // Тут мы вызываем этот же AsyncTask
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        runListenStatus(Integer.parseInt(order), Integer.parseInt(id_order));
                    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(OrderInfoMapActivity.this, "Проблема с соединением", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил возможно и не самым красивым путём, но по крайне мере, оно адекватно работает, решение положил на плечи TimerTask

```
 public void callAsynchronousTask(final int id_order, final int id) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        API_ORDER_GET_STATUS performBackgroundTask = new API_ORDER_GET_STATUS();
                        // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask
                        Map<String, String> arr = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        SharedPreferences sPref = OrderInfoMapActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String phone = sPref.getString("phone", "");
                        String hash = sPref.getString("hash", "");


                        arr.put("url", getResources().getString(R.string.api_order_status));
                        arr.put("phone", phone);
                        arr.put("hash", hash);
                        arr.put("order", Integer.toString(id_order));
                        arr.put("id_order", Integer.toString(id));

                        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        arr.put("imei", telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
                        performBackgroundTask.execute(arr);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000); //execute in every 50000 ms
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать для этого отдельный тред используя класс HandlerThread. Данный тред висит постоянно и ждет сообщений, так же есть возможность отправлять результаты в UI тред. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html